# (Python) how to remove whitespace after comma in text file

Tags: python

```
elemmmm.txt = """
abc1, abc2, abc3, abc abc4, abc abc abc5, abc6
abc1, abc2, abc abc3, abc abc abc abc 4
abc1, abc2, abc3
"""
```

When you load the file and separate the elements by commas,

```
with open('elemmmm.txt', 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    list_words = [i.split(',') for i in f]
    print(list_words[0][1])
    >>> abc2
```

When printed, the space after the comma is also printed.

```
print(list_words[0][0])
>>>abc1
print(list_words[0][1])
>>>abc2
print(list_words[0][3])
>>>abc abc4
print(list_words[1][3])
>>>abc abc abc abc 4
```

I want to print it after removing the space after the comma as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split by `(", ")` instead of `(",")`

```py
[i.split(', ') for i in f]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could split by ", ", but what if you had "abc1,abc", do you want this to be returned as a single word or you want it to be split. If you want it to be split, and to removespaces at both ends then

```py
list_words = [[w.strip() for w in i.split(',')] for i in f]
```

You could also use a regular expression, `re.compile(r",\s*")` to remove only spaces after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [rstrip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and use map to apply it to your list:

```py
list_words = [list(map(str.rstrip, i.split(', '))) for i in f]
```